# How to correctly restart a actor system and rejoin it to akka cluster which just left from?

Tags: c#, f#, akka.net, akka-cluster

What does "restart a actor system" mean for a akka cluster?
Supposed I have a seednode A and another node B, and these code are executed:

```
let clusterObjOnNodeB = Cluster.Get actorSystemB

clusterObjOnNodeB.JoinSeedNodes 
<| ImmutableList.Create<Address>(seq[
    Address.Parse @"path to node A"
]|>Seq.toArray)

clusterObjOnNodeB.Leave clusterObjOnNodeB.SelfAddress
```

How do I restart actorSystemB and rejoin to the cluster again without disposing actorSystemB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can gracefully make an actor system [leave](http://api.getakka.net/docs/stable/html/8DE8EC2.htm) its current cluster and rejoin it again (keep in mind that this is an async operation and won't happen immediately, so if you want to wait for it you can hook up to [removed](https://getakka.net/api/Akka.Cluster.Cluster.html#Akka_Cluster_Cluster_RegisterOnMemberRemoved_Action_) event).

This however is not equivalent to restarting an actor system, which usually means [terminating](https://getakka.net/api/Akka.Actor.ActorSystem.html#Akka_Actor_ActorSystem_Terminate) and starting it again. Reason for that is that there's usually a lot of internal state being kept by the actor system itself, that won't simply reset itself to some initial value. Sometimes state of individual actors may be entangled together into a form that is a cause of an issues. Restarting one - possibly uncorrelated - piece of system won't help in that case.